# Is it possible to override the built-in Angular 2 pipes so they can be used globally?

Tags: angular

I would like to override the "date" pipe and enjoy the benefit of global access everywhere just like the built-in pipe--aka, avoid having to import and use pipes[] array in every component annotation. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020473/override-angular-default-date-pipe

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020473/override-angular-default-date-pipe

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`PLATFORM_PIPES`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/platform_directives_and_pipes.ts#L53) to add a custom pipe and name that pipe `date` to hijack it.

```js
@Pipe({
   name : 'date' // Hijacks the 'date' pipe
})
class CustomDatePipe {
  transform(val, args) {
    return /* do something new with the value */;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : '{{mydate | date}}',
})
export class App {
  mydate = Date.now();
}

// Provides the CustomDatePipe globally
bootstrap(App, [provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: [CustomDatePipe], multi: true})]);
```

This way you won't have to add specify it every time in `pipes` property in your components.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rfcxvOpcTQcaiEP5xsHd?p=preview) with an example working.

Comment: Do you know what needs to be done so pipes are also globally available within unit tests?

Answer (score 5):

Eric Martinez' answer works fine! Just keep in mind that PLATFORM_PIPES is deprecated in Angular4. Platform pipes in Angular4 are configured via app.modules:

```
/**
 * `AppModule`
 */
 @NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
       ...
       CustomDatePipe
    ]
})
```

Comment: And for testing (to answer Vilmantas Baranauskas' question): you can write a test for the Pipe itself and in your test explicitely invoke transform, e.g. new CustomDatePipe().transform(input)

Comment: Deprecated! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56020657/9224219 for solution

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use PLATFORM_PIPES in following way

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/PLATFORM_PIPES-let.html

```
import {PLATFORM_PIPES} from '@angular/core';
import {OtherPipe} from './myPipe';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    {{123 | other-pipe}}
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  ...
}
bootstrap(MyComponent, [{provide: PLATFORM_PIPES, useValue: [OtherPipe], multi:true}]);
```