# Angular2 currency symbol

Tags: angular, pipe, currency

I'm in Australia trying to show some currency values, I'm doing

```
{{ portfolio.currentValue | currency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' }}
```

and I'm getting as result **A$1,300,000**, I would like to show **$1,300,000** (no A) without having to change to 'USD'.

Is there a way to customise my currency symbol?

Comment: It's not mentioned in [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html), so probably not. You could subclass or compose your own pipe for that behaviour, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your locale to Australia and then for AUD currency, it will just display a $.

In your app providers add the following:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-AU' }
```

Then the following will simply display a $ :

```
{{ portfolio.currentValue | currency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is whan you want, It will handle not only AUD but all currencies:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({
    name: "myCurrencyPipe"
})
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

    transform(value: any, currencyCode?: string, symbolDisplay?: boolean, digits?: string): string {

        let transformed = this.currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
        let myTransformed:string[] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < transformed.length; i++) {
            if(!this.isLetter(transformed[i])){
                myTransformed.push(transformed[i])
            }
        }

        return myTransformed.join("");
    }

    isLetter(c) {
        return c.toLowerCase() != c.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Call it like that : `{{ portfolio.currentValue | myCurrency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' }}`

First it will do all what the `CurrencyPipe` is doing by calling `this.currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);` then it is modifying the output by removing all letters from it.

`app.module.ts` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //..
    MyCurrencyPipe,
  ],
  providers: [
    //..
    CurrencyPipe
  ]
  //..
})
```

If you want to you create just a pipe that take care of `CurrencyPipe` output:

```
 @Pipe({
    name: 'removeLettersFromStringPipe'
})
export class RemoveLettersFromStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string){

    let myTransformed:string[] = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if(!this.isLetter(value[i])){
            myTransformed.push(value[i])
        }
    }

    return myTransformed.join("");
  }

  isLetter(c) {
      return c.toLowerCase() != c.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Use it as `{{ portfolio.currentValue | currency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' | removeLettersFromStringPipe}}`

Answer (score 0):

The [currencyPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html) does't provide this possibility. An option would be to write your own [custom pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) to remove the "A" and concat these pipes.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'removeAFromString'})
export class RemoveAFromString implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number){
    return value.substring(1);

  }
}
```

Now concat the pipes:

```
{{ portfolio.currentValue | currency : 'AUD' : true : '4.0' | removeAFromString}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but if it's not possible I would prefer a solution like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35044368/7520663)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answers, we've used a custom pipe for this as I too couldn't find a way to customise the symbol for AUD.

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'aud'
})
export class AudPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: number): any {

    if (value === undefined || value === null) {
        return null;
    }

    let numberPipe = new DecimalPipe('en-AU');
    return '$' + numberPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`symbol-narrow` is now supported, and will do what you need.

```
<!--output 'CA$0,001.35'-->
<p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol':'4.2-2'}}</p>

<!--output '$0,001.35'-->
<p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol-narrow':'4.2-2'}}</p>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#usage-notes

Works for AUD as well.