# Currency Pipe in Angular2

Tags: angular, currency, angular-pipe

I have a code that looks like this:

```
{{ currencyValue | currency : 'SGD' : true : '4.0' }}
```

Regrettably, its not showing a S$
Read from other articles that the Pipe used in Angular2 is using an ISO format but seems like there are currencies that ain't working(I guess? My basis for this is just this).
Tried USD, AUD and BRL and it works like charm but sadly, the opposite for SGD.

Any help is highly appreciated.

My references for this code are here:

[Angular2 currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058225/angular2-currency-symbol)

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php

Comment: This is wierd. For AUD it is giving `A$` but not for SGD. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058225/angular2-currency-symbol). May be you find something out of it .

Comment: @TheDictator weird right? as for the link, that's one of my references. yes i know i can create a custom pipe but that should be my last resort. maybe there's a workaround for this without creating a custom pipe, i guess?

Comment: I guess not ...