# AUD currency format

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

I would like to have the following Australian currency format using angular.

$50 AUD

Trying to use the currency pipe but looks like there is no easy way to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058225/angular2-currency-symbol"

Comment: @RaviAshara it is a different requirement. I need it in $50 AUD format

Comment: So you need to create custom pipe

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9n83ox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Check this link

Comment: @RaviAshara That's hardcoding. What's the point?

Comment: i am create custom pipe so you need to pass `currency` sign and `currency` code. if you  pass `currency` sign only then it's consider sign only. if you pass `currency` code  it's consider code

Comment: @RaviAshara it is easier if I just do $50 aud hardcoding. no difference with the custom pipe you did

Answer (score 1):

The currency pipe doesn't seem to support the format you want out of the box.

You should probably just make your own pipe for it. Something like:

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "aud",
  pure: true
})
export class AudDirective {
  transform(value: number | string, args?: any): any {
    return "$" + value + " AUD";
  }
}
```

Here's a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zvwqwt?file=src/app/aud.directive.ts) for it (feel free to expand the Pipe code to make it more robust/modulable)

Comment: I am looking for existing angular currency pipe functionalities. This looks more like hard coding.

Comment: Again, it doesn't come out of the box sadly, you can always expand their pipe like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669394/angular-5-currencypipe
You can also have a look at the CurrencyPipe internal code to see how they do it, and implement your pipe extension in a way that looks similar and not hard-coded

Answer (score 0):

there is an angular pipe called 'Currency Pipe' which you can use to format the value to a particular country's currency.

Please check this stackblitz for Australian Dollar

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txzp1b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Codes: USA ==> USD, Canada ==> CAD, Australia ==> AUD, India ==> INR

Comment: I need it in $50 AUD. 
With the dollar sign in front and AUD at the end.

Comment: Then I suggest, you  may try to write a custom pipe and format the currency

Comment: example? manually hardcoding AUD? dont think so