# Angular: Overriding DatePipe in node_module components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-pipe, angular-compiler

Problem: I have an external library in my angular app with components. Some of this components use Angular DatePipe internally to transform dates in the 'shortDate' format. I don't really have the option to use any other component or implement a custom one as it's a requirement for the client to use that specific library. But of course they don't want 'shortDate' format aswell.

I tried extendeding the built-in Angular DatePipe. As follows:

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'date'
})
export class DateExtendedPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  static readonly DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
  
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale)
  }

  transform(value: Date | string | number, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): string | null;
  transform(value: null | undefined, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): null;
  transform(value: Date | string | number | null | undefined, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): string | null {
    console.log('date format');
    
    const ghibFormat = format && format !== 'shortDate' ? format : DateExtendedPipe.DEFAULT_FORMAT;
    return super.transform(value, ghibFormat, timezone, locale);
  }

}
```

This works for any custom-component that i have currently implemented in my app. Whenever i use 'my_var | date' it triggers my extended pipe instead of Angular's.

As for node_modules components it still triggers the default Angular DatePipe instead of my extended one. I assume this has to do with the way the angular architecture is built and the compiler compiles node_modules first. Not entirely sure. Just wanted to see if anyone came accross a similiar problem, and if there's any magical solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the correct provider:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: DatePipe,
    useClass: MyDatePipe
  }]
```

This will provide MyDatePipe to everyone wanting DatePipe.

Apparently this is deprecated, and now you should simply add it in your App module declarations. See answer [Override Angular default date pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020473/override-angular-default-date-pipe/56020657#56020657)

Comment: Same behaviour. Works like a charm in components generated in my app, but doesn't work in components that come from node_modules libs.

Comment: Added a new method I just found.